# "org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException" when deploying Grails app on Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, grails

I'm having trouble deploying a webapp after upgrading to Grails v2.3.4. The Grails version that I used before was around v1.3

The webapp is fully functional when testing it in run-app or run-war locally. But when I deploy the war file on the remote server (Tomcat 7.0.6, Java 1.6.0_22), I get the following error:

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplication' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]:$
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1512)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:610)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
            at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
            at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
            at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoader.java:70)
            at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4521)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5004)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:4999)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.io.support.IOUtils.createXmlSlurper()Lgroovy/util/XmlSlurper;
            at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsApplicationFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(GrailsApplicationFactoryBean.java:64)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1571)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1509)
            ... 21 more 
2013-12-17 18:38:07,999 [Thread-2] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.io.support.IOUtils.createXmlSlurper()Lgroovy/util/XmlSlurper;
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsApplicationFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(GrailsApplicationFactoryBean.java:64)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1571)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1509)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:610)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:610)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoader.java:70)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4521)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5004)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:4999)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Any ideas highly appreciated.

Comment: Errors in `java.lang` almost always point to different version issues. You must be using a newer version that doesn't have an older method.

Comment: how about showing us your ApplicationContext.xml

Comment: Check the jars, you probably have something missing in your war.

Comment: I agree with Sotirios. You probably have some older grails jars mixed in with new ones after the upgrade. look in the web-inf/lib folder and look for conflicts. they are all versioned so it should stand out